# Парсинг свойства из json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

```
console.log(data.hash); //undefined
console.log(data); //{"hash":"06dac36ca5690be019cbb79b2de2b875"}
```

Не могу понять почему получаю `undefined` когда обращаюсь напрямую к переменной, или что я делаю не так?

Json получаю из php с таким вот содержанием

```
print json_encode(['hash'=>$hash]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На клиенте вы должны были распарсить JSON-строку, полученную в ответе и чего, собственно, я у вас не наблюдаю.

```js
let data = JSON.parse('{"hash":"06dac36ca5690be019cbb79b2de2b875"}');
console.log(data.hash);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {
  "hash": "06dac36ca5690be019cbb79b2de2b875"
}

console.log(data['hash']); // 06dac36ca5690be019cbb79b2de2b875
```

Comment: мне нужно из пхп передать массив на страницу

Comment: @user254893 и в вопросе это тоже нужно указывать изначально